# Values with special character end up different in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

**adress.js**

```
function addAdress(){
var s = document.getElementById('addStreetName').value;
var sn = document.getElementById('addStreetNumber').value;
var sl = document.getElementById('addStreetLittera').value;
var sz = document.getElementById('addZipCode').value;
var sa = document.getElementById('addAreaCode').value;

$.ajax({
    url: 'db/addAdress.inc.php',
    type:'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 
        addStreetName: s,
        addStreetNumber: sn,
        addStreetLittera: sl,
        addZipCode: sz,
        addAreaCode: sa
    },
    success: function(output_string){
        $('#addAdressResultBox').append(output_string);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
  }
});
}
```

**addAdress.inc.php**

```
include('../inc/conn.inc.php');

$query = "INSERT INTO comhem_profiler_adresses (comhem_profiler_adresses_street, comhem_profiler_adresses_street_number, comhem_profiler_adresses_littera, comhem_profiler_adresses_zip_code, comhem_profiler_adresses_area_code)
VALUES ('" . $_POST['addStreetName'] . "', '" . $_POST['addStreetNumber'] . "', '" . $_POST['addStreetLittera'] . "', '" . $_POST['addZipCode'] . "', '" . $_POST['addAreaCode'] . "'";
$addAdress = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_close();
```

In this script I want to add adresses to the database. But when they end up in the database the special characters å ä ö en up as completly other charcters. Sörbyvägen ends up like SÃ¶rbyvÃ¤gen. I do not know where to look the change this.

It does not seem to be the database as i took a script to change these to their html counterparts. SÃ¶rbyvÃ¤gen still appeard in the database but with the html counterparts. And tried htmlspecialchars(). Still appeared as SÃ¶rbyvÃ¤gen in the database.

Any idea?

Comment: Side note: please Google for Little Bobby Tables.

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your table's `default-character-set` is `utf8` and `default-collation` is `utf8_general_ci`

Also make sure after connecting to MySQL you use `mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $connection);`

Comment: Without forgetting `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");` or `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` in apache config

Answer (score 0):

U need to correctly encode such character to UTF-8 as well as setting up your database to work with UTF-8, thenit will work like a charm. Also you need to know what was the base encoding to convert it correctly to utf-8